# jQuery dialog popup behind my blog content. How to fix

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, dialog

I have this problem I have dealing with for a while now. My dialog appears to pop up behind my blog content. here is a screenshot.
http://wsoplugins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Capture.png
can someone help me fix this?
It pops up behind the header content to be specific. The other content below seems fine.
thank you so much.

```
.ui-dialog{

position: fixed;
z-index: 99999;

}
```

Comment: What are the computed CSS properties of your header and of your dialog popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your `z-index`.

For example:

```
#myPopup{
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

**EDIT**
There's your problem:

```
position: fixed;
```

Your position needs to be `relative` or `absolute`.

Comment: thank you DC finally got it working. the position thing. God that was easy. thanks again.

Comment: what if my position has to be fixed - for the middle of the screen in a scrollable one?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your zIndex option while creating dialog with;

```
zIndex: 12000 //you can set much more
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is wise to put `z-index` property on adjacent element-wrappers. The only thing that needed for `z-index` to work is that the elements should be positioned relatively, absolutely or fixed via `position` property.

e.g. HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
Multiple div's here with some text or whatever elements, some of them with z-index
</div>
<div class="main_content">
Multiple div's here with some text or whatever elements, some of them with z-index
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    position: relative; //fixed, or absolute, otherwise z-index doesn't work
    z-index: 40;
}
.main_content{
    position: relative; //fixed, or absolute, otherwise z-index doesn't work
    z-index: 30; // setting it lower than the previous block
}
```

you may add such css to make sure that anything that goes after the `nav` in the `main_content` div will be positioned with a lower `z-index` value.